# Naming output iterating raster clips based on vector features id in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I'm working with QGIS 3.22.15-Białowieża and I've got a raster layer `corine` with Corine Land Cover data and a vector layer `nests` with 1 km buffer areas around raptors nests. I want to analyze the land cover present within each buffer area. My best bet is to make an iterating clipping on the original raster to obtain one raster layer for each nest buffer zone, so I can subsequently run a `Raster layer unique values report` on each of these layers.

The problem is that, as far as I can see, the iteration produces output files named with consecutive numbers.

Is there a way to identify (name) these output files according to the id (or whatever other attribute) of the vector feature?

Comment: You dont need to iterate. You can use one [Zonal histogram](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalhistogram) to get one column for each class with the pixel count. Then Multiply each with the pixel size to get area

Comment: I don't think that would work, since I need the pixel count per class AND per nest buffer. Besides, some buffers do overlap, so I need separate clips for each one.